# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. flutter

Tags: android, flutter

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\Pemula.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.96\descriptors\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\a8be1fe3b3911d3d3425fe720cf42835\descriptor.bin

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please share full error log

Comment: did you updated android studio. if not, Please update to latest version